# Is it possible to access both my Django project and Nginx Server on a single port forwarding?

Tags: django, devops, hosting, nginx-config

My Django project is running on http://127.0.0.1:8000/
and Nginx Server is running on http://127.0.0.1:8080/

I want to access both on a single port forwarding (8081).

Host Django and Nginx on the same port on the windows server.

I've docker compose as:

version: '3'
services:
web:
build: .
command: sh -c "echo 'Making migrations ' && python manage.py makemigrations && echo 'Migrating...' && python manage.py migrate && echo 'Running server...' && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
volumes:
- .:/code
ports:
- "8000:8000"
restart: always
nginx-allure:
image: nginx
container_name: nginx-allure
ports:
- "8080:80"
volumes:
- type: bind
source: ./allure-reports
target: /usr/share/nginx/html
read_only: true
restart: always

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use both of them on the same port. However, what you can do is serve Nginx on port 8081 and redirect the requests for Django from Nginx to port 8080 of Django using proxy_pass.